# LibVLC: marquee and full screen issues

Tags: libvlc

I am currently trying to use LibVLC to play videos and have some questions:

1. On a computer with multiple screens, how do I tell LibVLC to show full screen on a specific screen?
2. I try to use `libvlc_video_set_marquee_int`. After some trail and error I found out, that it works when I pause the main thread after starting the video for about 70ms before setting a marquee text. Why? How can I do this better?
3. I want to show a marquee text, but no video title (LibVLC displays the video title or file name in the beginning). I read that you could disable the video title by passing the `--no-video-title-show` option to `libvlc_new()`. However this has two problems: First the documentation says one should not pass options. Well, ok... But secondly using this option has a strange effect on marquee texts: You can set a text, but it just blinks once and disappears immediately, no matter what `libvlc_marquee_Timeout` is set to.

Comment: I realize it has been quite some time since you asked this question, but I am having the exact same problem you describe in #3. Further after the marquee shows briefly it never shows again despite key presses, which have been coded to create a such a response. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I switched to MPlayer instead. It looked like it worked better in the beginning, although it's complicated to use. But I later found out, that it only works once. If you want to play a second video and also want some subtitle, it simply doesn't work.  
So far I have not been able to find any portable option of showing text over video.  
But it sounds like you found a workaround. Would you mind sharing and/or explaining it in a little more detail?

Answer (score 5):

Just this morning I think I got to the bottom of it with the help of the folks over at videolan forums.  I should mention that I am working on linux system, I don't know what OS you are using, but I know there are some differences.  Here's what I did:

First, I found it useful to get the marquee working on the command line first. Here is a link to the discussion on this topic:

http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=110743

The command line options that worked for me:

```
 cvlc --extraintf=http:logger --verbose=2 --file-logging --logfile=vlc-log.txt --sub-source="marq{marquee=marquee text here}" test.mpg
```

I had an issue along the way where even with the above command I could not get the marquee to show.  On my gentoo system I needed to rebuild vlc with fontconfig and truetype enabled.

Now with cvlc displaying a marquee on a video, I moved back to libvlc.  I was missing something, so I started another discussion here:

http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=110783

The snippets of C / libvlc code that ultimately allowed me to show a marquee on demand without the filename marquee are provided below.

In main:

```
const char * const vlc_args[] = {
"--extraintf=http:logger",
"--verbose=1",
"--file-logging",
"--logfile=/home/user/data/logs/vlc",
"--no-video-title-show",                // <- this option disables the filename marquee
"--sub-filter=marq"};                   // <- this option allows the on demand marquee to display properly

vlc_inst = libvlc_new (sizeof(vlc_args) / sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);
```

In keypress callback:

```
        libvlc_video_set_marquee_int(media_player, 0, 1);       /* enable marquee */
        libvlc_video_set_marquee_int(media_player, 6, 32);      /* set marquee font size */
        libvlc_video_set_marquee_int(media_player, 7, 2000);    /* set marquee timeout (ms) */
        libvlc_video_set_marquee_string(media_player, 1, "on demand marquee string here");
```

Hopefully some of this will help you get a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Sorry, at the moment I can't give you any credit since I cannot validate the answer, due to a lack of time. As soon as I find the time, I will check it.